Single-Digit BCD Adder
I have this code written in SystemVerilog. The module bcdadd1 is supposed to take in two 4-bit inputs A and B and a logic input carryin (ci). The module has two outputs: sum (s), which is 4-bit, and carryout (co). The module should function as a single-digit BCD adder. More concisely, if the result of the sum is greater than 9 we should add 6 to the sum and set co to logic high. Otherwise, the sum is already a BCD and we do not need to modify co.
I can't seem to find a way to modify co without my compiler complaining about an "inferred latch." If I manage to include it without error, the functionality is not correct and it seems to not add 6 to the sum. I would greatly appreciate any help. I do not have access to our test bench, as we interact with a simulator within a webpage. If it helps, there is a GitHub repository for the webpage.
`default_nettype none

module top (
  // I/O ports
  input  logic hz100, reset,
  input  logic [20:0] pb,
  output logic [7:0] left, right,
         ss7, ss6, ss5, ss4, ss3, ss2, ss1, ss0,
  output logic red, green, blue,

  // UART ports
  output logic [7:0] txdata,
  input  logic [7:0] rxdata,
  output logic txclk, rxclk,
  input  logic txready, rxready
);

  logic co;
  logic [3:0] s;
  bcdadd1 ba1(.a(pb[3:0]), .b(pb[7:4]), .ci(pb[19]), .co(co), .s(s), .r(red), .test({left[7:0], right[7:0]}));
  ssdec s0(.in(s), .out(ss0[6:0]), .enable(1));
  ssdec s1(.in({3'b0,co}), .out(ss1[6:0]), .enable(1));
  ssdec s5(.in(pb[7:4]), .out(ss5[6:0]), .enable(1));
  ssdec s7(.in(pb[3:0]), .out(ss7[6:0]), .enable(1));

endmodule

module fa(
  input logic a, b, ci,
  output logic s, co
);
  assign {co,s} = a + b + ci;
endmodule

module fa4(
  input logic [3:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [3:0] s,
  output logic co
);
  logic c0, c1, c2;
  fa f1(.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]), .ci(ci), .s(s[0]), .co(c0));
  fa f2(.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .ci(c0), .s(s[1]), .co(c1));
  fa f3(.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .ci(c1), .s(s[2]), .co(c2));
  fa f4(.a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .ci(c2), .s(s[3]), .co(co));
endmodule

//Trouble here:
**
module bcdadd1(
  input logic [3:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [3:0] s,
  output logic co, r,
  output logic [15:0] test
);
  logic [3:0] sum;
  
  fa4 f1(.a(a), .b(b), .ci(ci), .s(sum), .co(co));
  
  always_comb begin
    if (sum > 4'b1001) begin
      s = sum + 4'b0110;
    end 
    else begin
      s = sum;
    end
  end
  assign test[11:8] = a;
  assign test[7:4] = b;
  assign r = co;
  assign test[3:0] = s;
endmodule
**

/* Seven-Segment Decoder */
module ssdec(
  input logic [3:0] in,
  input logic enable,
  output logic [6:0] out
);
logic [15:0] sA, sB, sC, sD, sE, sF, sG;

  assign sA = 16'b1101011111101101;
  assign sB = 16'b0010011110011111;
  assign sC = 16'b0010111111111011;
  assign sD = 16'b0111100101101101;
  assign sE = 16'b1111110101000101;
  assign sF = 16'b1101111101110001;
  assign sG = 16'b1110111101111100;

  assign out[0] = sA[in] & enable;
  assign out[1] = sB[in] & enable;
  assign out[2] = sC[in] & enable;
  assign out[3] = sD[in] & enable;
  assign out[4] = sE[in] & enable;
  assign out[5] = sF[in] & enable;
  assign out[6] = sG[in] & enable;

endmodule

module bcdadd4(
  input logic [15:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [15:0] s,
  output logic co
);
  logic co_b1, co_b2, co_b3;
 
  bcdadd1 b1(.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .ci(ci), .s(s[3:0]), .co(co_b1));
  bcdadd1 b2(.a(a[7:4]), .b(b[7:4]), .ci(co_b1), .s(s[7:4]), .co(co_b2));
  bcdadd1 b3(.a(a[11:8]), .b(b[11:8]), .ci(co_b2), .s(s[11:8]), .co(co_b3));
  bcdadd1 b4(.a(a[15:12]), .b(b[15:12]), .ci(co_b3), .s(s[15:12]), .co(co));
endmodule

module bcd9comp1(
  input  logic [3:0] in,
  output logic [3:0] out
);
  always_comb begin
    case (in)
      4'b0000: out = 4'b1001;
      4'b0001: out = 4'b1000;
      4'b0010: out = 4'b0111;
      4'b0011: out = 4'b0110;
      4'b0100: out = 4'b0101;
      4'b0101: out = 4'b0100;
      4'b0110: out = 4'b0011;
      4'b0111: out = 4'b0010;
      4'b1000: out = 4'b0001;
      4'b1001: out = 4'b0000;
      default: out = 4'b0000;
    endcase
  end

endmodule

module bcdaddsub4(
  input  logic [15:0] a, b,
  input  logic op,
  output logic [15:0] s
);

  logic [3:0] ten_comp_a[3:0];
  logic [3:0] ten_comp_b[3:0];
  logic [3:0] operand[3:0];    

  bcd9comp1 comp_a0(.in(a[3:0]), .out(ten_comp_a[0]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_a1(.in(a[7:4]), .out(ten_comp_a[1]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_a2(.in(a[11:8]), .out(ten_comp_a[2]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_a3(.in(a[15:12]), .out(ten_comp_a[3]));

  bcd9comp1 comp_b0(.in(b[3:0]), .out(ten_comp_b[0]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_b1(.in(b[7:4]), .out(ten_comp_b[1]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_b2(.in(b[11:8]), .out(ten_comp_b[2]));
  bcd9comp1 comp_b3(.in(b[15:12]), .out(ten_comp_b[3]));

  always_comb begin
    if (op == 0) begin
      operand[0] = a[3:0];  
      operand[1] = a[7:4];
      operand[2] = a[11:8];
      operand[3] = a[15:12];
    end
    else begin
      operand[0] = ten_comp_a[0];
      operand[1] = ten_comp_a[1];
      operand[2] = ten_comp_a[2];
      operand[3] = ten_comp_a[3];
    end
  end


  bcdadd4 adder(.a({operand[3], operand[2], operand[1], operand[0]}), .b({ten_comp_b[3],ten_comp_b[2],ten_comp_b[1],ten_comp_b[0]}), .ci(op), .s(s), .co());

endmodule


It is so much easier when you create your own testbench code to debug Verilog problems.  I created the tb module with an instance of your bcdadd1 module and some very simple input data.
In the BCD module, I created an internal cout signal which is connected to the co output of the full adder.  Then it is a simple assign to drive the co output of the BCD:
module bcdadd1(
  input logic [3:0] a, b,
  input logic ci,
  output logic [3:0] s,
  output logic co, r,
  output logic [15:0] test
);
  logic [3:0] sum;
  logic cout;
  
  fa4 f1(.a(a), .b(b), .ci(ci), .s(sum), .co(cout));

  assign co = (sum > 4'b1001) ? 1 : cout;

  always_comb begin
    if (sum > 4'b1001) begin
      s = sum + 4'b0110;
    end 
    else begin
      s = sum;
    end
  end

  assign test[11:8] = a;
  assign test[7:4] = b;
  assign r = co;
  assign test[3:0] = s;
endmodule

module tb;
    bit [3:0] a;
    bit [3:0] b;
    bit ci;
    wire co;
    wire r;
    wire [3:0] s;
    wire [15:0] test;

bcdadd1 dut (
    .a     (a),
    .b     (b),
    .ci    (ci),
    .co    (co),
    .r     (r),
    .s     (s),
    .test  (test)
);

initial begin
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) begin
        {a, b} = i;
        #5;
    end
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule

Output:


That's a very useful addition, this is not a practice we have been taught as it is more or less handed to us through black boxes. Perhaps my post was a little bit too vague, as I have problems in the functionality of my code as well. The co is indeed working, or at least it seems, but s is not being properly adjusted. This shows up on the fpga as 8 8 10, indicating 8+8=10, with the co light being asserted (the 10's place represents co). I've taken a look at the test bench and it seems useful, but it is largely new to me so I am unsure about how to properly utilize the traces.

@David: It sounds like you have another problem with your code.  I recommend you Accept this answer since it solves the problem with co, then post a new question.
